# Plotting colormap graph for each day side by side

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib

I have the following 2 column data:

```
Time            PRESSURE 
2/24/2016 13:00 1011.937618
2/24/2016 14:00 1011.721583
2/24/2016 15:00 1011.348064
2/24/2016 16:00 1011.30785
2/24/2016 17:00 1011.3198
2/24/2016 18:00 1011.403372
2/24/2016 19:00 1011.485108
2/24/2016 20:00 1011.270083
2/24/2016 21:00 1010.936331
2/24/2016 22:00 1010.920958
2/24/2016 23:00 1010.816478
2/25/2016 00:00 1010.899142
2/25/2016 01:00 1010.209392
2/25/2016 02:00 1009.700625
2/25/2016 03:00 1009.457683
2/25/2016 04:00 1009.268081
2/25/2016 05:00 1009.718639
2/25/2016 06:00 1010.745444
2/25/2016 07:00 1011.062028
2/25/2016 08:00 1011.168117
2/25/2016 09:00 1010.771281
2/25/2016 10:00 1010.138053
2/25/2016 11:00 1009.509119
2/25/2016 12:00 1008.703811
2/25/2016 13:00 1008.021547
2/25/2016 14:00 1007.774825
  .....................
```

And I want to create a plot with X axis of days (2/25 , 2/26, ... , 3/25) and Y axis of Time (00:00, 01:00, ..., 23:00).
On each day I want an intensity graph of the Pressure for each hour.
So the result chart should have a bar of intensity for each day side by side. I've tried with matlab to create a variable for one day (2 columns because i'm trying to interpolate for a greater resolution):

```
data =
1010.89914200000    1010.89914200000
1010.20939200000    1010.20939200000
1009.70062500000    1009.70062500000
1009.45768300000    1009.45768300000
1009.26808100000    1009.26808100000
1009.71863900000    1009.71863900000
1010.74544400000    1010.74544400000
1011.06202800000    1011.06202800000
1011.16811700000    1011.16811700000
1010.77128100000    1010.77128100000
1010.13805300000    1010.13805300000
1009.50911900000    1009.50911900000
1008.70381100000    1008.70381100000
1008.02154700000    1008.02154700000
1007.77482500000    1007.77482500000
1007.69477800000    1007.69477800000
1007.77405000000    1007.77405000000
1008.10153900000    1008.10153900000
1008.42932800000    1008.42932800000
1008.61755800000    1008.61755800000
1008.56708100000    1008.56708100000
1008.29791700000    1008.29791700000
1008.21371700000    1008.21371700000
1007.63143900000    1007.63143900000
```

and plotted as follows:

```
%// Define integer grid of coordinates for the above data
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:size(data,2), 1:size(data,1));

%// Define a finer grid of points
[X2,Y2] = meshgrid(1:0.01:size(data,2), 1:0.01:size(data,1));

%// Interpolate the data and show the output
outData = interp2(X, Y, data, X2, Y2, 'linear');
imagesc(outData);

%// Cosmetic changes for the axes
set(gca, 'XTick', linspace(1,size(X2,2),size(X,2))); 
set(gca, 'YTick', linspace(1,size(X2,1),size(X,1)));
set(gca, 'XTickLabel', 1:size(X,2));
set(gca, 'YTickLabel', 1:size(X,1));

%// Add colour bar
colorbar;
```

and got the following:

[image]

But i'm looking for a way to do this for the rest of the days and plot it side by side!
(Hope now the question is better)

Thank you !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a `python` approach to making a "calendar plot" that makes use of `numpy`, `pandas`, and especially `matplotlib`.

1) Generate data

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# arbitrary hourly time series data (from 11/9/2014 to 1/17/15)
time = pd.date_range(start='20141109', end='20150117', freq='H')[:-1]

# sinusoidal "pressure" data with minor noise added
x = np.linspace(-2*np.pi, 2*np.pi, num=time.size)
pressure = np.sin(x) + 100
noise = np.random.normal(0, 0.1, pressure.size)
noisy_pressure = pressure + noise
```

2) Create array of `int`s corresponding to months. These will later be used for iterating over to label each plot

```
# pick out months from time array using filtering with np.diff
months = time.month[:-1][np.diff(time.month) != 0]
months = np.append(months, time.month[-1])
# months = array([11, 12, 1]) corresponding to Nov, Dec, Jan
```

3) Set up x and y axes for plots using `np.meshgrid`

```
hours = np.unique(time.hour) # array([0,1,2,...,21,22,23])
X, hours_2d = np.meshgrid([0, 1], hours)
```

4) Plot calendar using `matplotlib.gridspec` to set up axes and `plt.pcolormesh` to make color plots of data

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec
from calendar import month_name

cols = 7 # corresponding to days of the week
rows = 5 # int(np.ceil(31/7)), 31=max(days in a month)
num_days = rows * cols

for i, month in enumerate(months):
    gs = gridspec.GridSpec(rows, cols)
    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.suptitle(month_name[month], size='x-large')

    for day in range(num_days):
        # filter pressure on a daily basis according to month and day
        daily_pressure = noisy_pressure[(time.month==month) & (time.day==day+1)]
        # need to tile array in order to plot it with plt.pcolormesh
        daily_pressure_2d = np.tile(daily_pressure, (2, 1)).T

        if daily_pressure_2d.size > 0:
            ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[day])
            cmesh = ax.pcolormesh(X, hours_2d, daily_pressure_2d,
                                  vmin=noisy_pressure.min(),
                                  vmax=noisy_pressure.max())
            # remove x and y ticklabels and x tick marks
            ax.set_xticklabels([]); ax.set_xticks([])
            ax.set_yticklabels([])
            ax.set_xlabel('{month} {day}'.format(
                month=month_name[month][:3], day=day+1))
            ax.set_ylim((hours.min(), hours.max()))
        else:
            # basically create an empty plot for days without pressure data
            ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[day])
            ax.axis('off')

    plt.tight_layout() # for nicer formatting
    fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.9) # create room for suptitle
    fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.85) # create room for colorbar
    # create colorbar with customized location
    cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([0.87, 0.05, 0.03, 0.85])
    fig.colorbar(cmesh, cax=cbar_ax)
```

5) Admire output -- a similar plot is created for each month in the date range

[image]

Comment: Links to [November](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lqaf3.png) and [January](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Pi1mr.png) plots.

Comment: This is Dec 2013 or 2002 (at least in USA and UK) as it starts on Sunday... Add blank spaces at the beginning so that it's more like a real calendar page.. of course I've already upvoted...

Comment: While I like your suggestion @gboffi, after fiddling around for a little while I think it may cause more trouble than it's worth. You can get the offset using `datetime.datetime(year, month, day).weekday()`, but it doesn't seem to be as easy as adding the offset to `gs[day]`. Since the primary purpose is simply for data visualization and not actual correspondence to the calendar, I will leave that as an exercise for the reader :)